# I am experiencing a "could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

`

```
//soldity is synchronous lang

const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
  //http://127.0.0.1:7545
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
  );
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "5248c9dfa1d4fb6369c105999f1362867d6acd5cf1dee7ef949870231520fa4f",
    provider
  );
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf8"
  );
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(); //stop here and wait for the contract to deploy
  console.log(contract);
}

main()
  .then(() => ProcessingInstruction.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

`

The error is -

```
Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (/root/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/root/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
```

So, I am working with JavaScript and solidity and developing a contract. While deploying the contract on a ganache network using node (all code in VS), I am experiencing this network error. PLeasee help! I am trying to learn and have been trying to solve this. Below is the code.

Answer (score 1):

Because Ganache is not connected to the WSL enviroment. So, go to the setting of the Ganache and choose the WSL as the server HOSTNAME.Finally, change the RPC in your code. Then it will be done.

```
let provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "HTTP://172.20.80.1:7545"
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using WSL subsystem (don't know if it's your case) because my ganache was running on windows while VScode was running on WSL.

I solved the problem using the terminal to installe ganache on WSL:

```
npm install -g ganache
```

Then run ganache:

```
ganache
```

It will give you some Private Keys, use one of them for your code, and then it show the IP that you have to use in your code:

```
RPC Listening on 127.0.0.1:3456 //or something similar
```

Keep ganache running in this terminal and open another one to run "node deploy.js"

Answer (score 0):

You might be running this from a WSL terminal, I tried running node deploy.js through windows PowerShell or Command prompt and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Open Your files in vs code without WSL enviornment and then run in terminal it will work because we have installed ganache in windows not in linux